How can I do some sort of limited dissolve of useless vertices at the edges?
Is there a way to do some limited dissolve either through the built-in Blender tools or perhaps through scripting (if not possible through Blender tools) to remove these types of vertices? Or do I have to remove them manually? I have thousands of these types of vertices. They cause the faces to become non-planar which I try to avoid.


oh i just realized i could select all vertices at the edge and write a python script that checks if the vertex has only 2 linked edges then dissolve. anyone interested please add your answer and i will accept. but i was also interested if there are any blender modeling techniques available as well to tackle this problem? or is python the only way?

Or you can write your own answer with the script?

@moonboots actually im really interested in a blender built-in tool for this. so are you saying it's not possible without python? or manually select the vertices? :)

I guess you've already tried Shift G and it doesn't work?

@moonboots hey that's exactly what i was looking for! thank you so much! please post as answer and i'll accept!

Try ShiftG (Select Similar) and one of its options
