Merge two edges on the same axis
I have done lots of searching, but it seems I can't get my wording correctly. I have multiple edges like


Where there are two edges on the same line (that share the center vertex), but I cant seem to find a way to merge them into one edge without deleting the center vertex and remaking the faces manually

You can't find a way? There are multiple ways to do this. Apart from dissolving the vertex which you answered yourself, you could also select a second neighbouring vertex and then press M > Merge > At Last or At First depending on the order in which you selected them. Or select the center vertex, then G G to edge slide onto another vertex and Merge > By Distance. Or enable the Auto Merge option so that after sliding onto another vertex they get merged automatically. Or snap one vertex to another with Auto Merge or merging by distance afterwards.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/316889/how-can-i-do-some-sort-of-limited-dissolve-of-useless-vertices-at-the-edges

@HarryMcKenzie Surely helpful for finding those vertices, but the question here is how to get rid of them. Dissolve Vertices is already given in the answer by the OP himself, Limited Dissolve (which you mention in your question) I suggested in the comment below the answer, but is allegedly not working for some unknown reason...

While I was making this, I remembered about dissolve vertices. By clicking on the middle vertex, and pressing X then choosing Dissolve Vertices, it seems to delete the center vertex and merge the edges connected to it.

If you have a lot like these, you could also select the whole mesh and then X > Limited Dissolve to get rid of all vertices and edges which are below a certain threshold angle. By default this is 5° which might be too high for meshes with low angles which you might want to keep, so you have to adjust the threshold when using this (I usually set it to 0.1° to make sure only straight/flat parts get dissolved).

Hmm, It seems it only works on faces, though. I had 20 of these, and doing it less manually was still better

No, it does not only work on faces. But without your mesh or an example it is hard to determine where this impression comes from. Since you got what you need it doesn't matter anymore I guess.

you can select the vertex and press Shift+G then try some of those options to automatically select all similar vertices as the one you selected. I think it was Shift+G > Amount of Connecting Edges. Then X > Dissolve Vertices. I had the same problem: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/316889/how-can-i-do-some-sort-of-limited-dissolve-of-useless-vertices-at-the-edges
